# how does CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL work?

Tags: cocoa, macos, network-programming

Is it using DHCP? DNS? what techniques does it use to return a set of proxy suggestions to the caller? Is it parallel to the "Auto Proxy Discovery" in the OSX network settings?

I can't find any information about this online. Apple's reference may just as well be written in egyptian symbols. I can't figure out what goes in "CFDictionaryRef proxySettings" in that method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses SystemConfiguration.framework to look up the proxy information. The URL determines the type of service, which determines which proxy setting to use. It may also affect how PAC files are evaluated.

Comment: so, you're saying, when i set up the myriad of proxy options in my MacOSX settings/network/advanced/proxies and use a browser to go to a certain URL, the **same mechanism** that would work for that, would work to resolve which proxy (if any) to use, would be used for the URL I dish out to this function?